# How can I keep my sub-menu open in jQuery hover menu - please check sample

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

You can see sample code from here [Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/a8yZb/)

The Goal:

1. When top menu hover, top menu and sub menu must open
2. when sub menu hover, top menu and sub menu must stay opened
3. when mouse out both top menu and submenu menus must close

I tried many times and searched for solutions but cant achieve.

Also I cant put sub menu under a element. Because when a shrinks(gets wither) the sub menu relatively changes its position. It's not compatible for me.

```
                <div class="menu-item"><a href="index.html"><i class="halflings white cog"></i> <span>Link One</span></a>
                    <div style="height:0;position:absolute;">
                    <div class="sub-menu" data-hover='false'>
                        <div>Sub Link</div>
                        <div>Sub Link</div>
                        <div>Sub Link</div>
                        <div>Sub Link</div>
                    </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue, by using these functions:

```
setTimeout(); 
clearTimeout();
```

The solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/a8yZb/55/

Answer (score 1):

You are using closing sub-menu's code:

```
 $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').css({display: "none"})
 .stop(true, false).animate({width:'0',height:'0',opacity:1},'fast');
```

in the wrong place. You can close it just after hover is false (like is in the another hover function). Then, invert this 'if' logic:

```
if(!$(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').data('hover'))
```

to:

```
if($(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').data('hover'))
```

and for end just add this 'if' after the another 'if':

```
if(!$(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').is(':visible')){
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({width:'15px'},'fast');                    
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8yZb/52/

Comment: But when submenu visible the top menu must stay opened, that is the problem.

Comment: @user3379494 i have edited the fiddle just changing the if logic on the closing code.

Comment: but this time the top menu doesn't close when hover out (outside submenu), there is hover issue, which I couldn't solve.

Comment: Ok @user3379494, i have edited the whole answer again (including the fiddle).

Comment: There is one problem, when top menu has submenu, and when hovering on it, and hovering out to downside or upside, the top menu doesn't disappears,  it only disappears after hover out submenu. Maybe we must use setTimeout functions. I tried but it doesn't work properly too, maybe I did wrong somewhere. And thanks for your effort @wistcc